# String list identity in where clause of JPA / JPQL Query

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

Say I have an `@Entity` like

```
class C {
  List<String> sequence;
}
```

and I want to query for instances of `C` that exactly match a given list. (I am aware that this is order sensitive, and I'm ok with that.) I am using EclipseLink and query with JPQL.

I tried the obvious:

```
List<String> querySeq = ... // some list to be used in the where clause
em.createQuery("select c from C c where c.sequence = :qs", C.class)
            .setParameter("qs", querySeq);
```

This fails when I try to execute the query with `getResultList()`. The error is  `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: row column count mismatch`.

I also tried with `join`:

```
select c from C c join c.sequence s where s in :qs
```

But this fails, too, saying `The collection-valued path 'c.sequence' must resolve to an association field.` My interpretation of this is that `join` does not work on a collection of primitives, but only on relations.

So my questions are:

What is the right way to do this?

Also, is there a way to do more complex operations on primitive collections, like querying for (set) intersections, unions or differences?

Comment: How is the entity represented in the DB?

Comment: @PradeepPati Isn't not having to consider this question one of the main arguments for using an ORM? ;-)

Comment: `em.createQuery` cannot be mapped to an entity explicitly. Do you mean `createNativeQuery`? and if mean that, then your query should look like:
`select sequence from C c where c.sequence = :qs`. also you shouldn't use `List<String> sequence` because the result you get is a list of entities.

Comment: @pmp Sorry, I don't understand your comment. I use `em.createQuery` with class parameter, which creates a `TypedQuery<T>`, from which I can receive a typed result list. I want the list of `C`s for which `c.sequence` matches the given sequence (i.e. list).

Comment: Are you using JPA JPQL or Hibernate?

Comment: JPA JPQL with EclipseLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any solution or article where JPQL could be used to directly compare lists. But there is a mechanism where you can test if a value is **MEMBER OF** the collection.

The process is not elegant but with a bit of tweaking we could build a query similar to this (Couldn't test the code, but I think it depicts the idea and 
logically should work):

```
String query = "SELECT c FROM C c";
String checkValue = "";

for(int i = 0; i<queryString.size();i++){

    checkValue = queryString.get(i);

    if(i==queryString.size()-1){
        query += " WHERE '" + checkValue + "'" + " MEMBER OF c.sequence";
    }else{
        query += " WHERE '" + checkValue + "'" + " MEMBER OF c.sequence AND";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure every MEMBER OF is also a subquery. So this is an n+1 approach unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

After research on the internet and the JPA specification, I see that we cannot compare two lists using the JPQL.

I suggest to select the entire list and then compare it with the second list using the Apache Commons [CollectionUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html). It offers the functionality of [intersection](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#intersection(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)) and [subtraction](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#subtract(java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable)).

Comment: What do you mean by "select the entire list"? Retrieving all entities from the DB is precisely what I want to avoid using a query.